# Transferring 'Live' Documents to Another Computer

Tags: software-rec, operating-systems

I was wondering if there was any OS/Application that has some support for transferring a document to another computer without having to save, transfer and then reopen. Basically, is there a way so that if I'm working on my desktop, I can click a button (or something similar) and then have the exact state of that computer/application transferred to another?

For example, if I'm writing a document, is there a way to get it to computer B without saving it, putting the file on my flash drive, and having to reopen it?

*Edit*: I just realized that this is possible through the wonderful phenomena known as cloud computing, but this is not the type of solution I'm looking for.

*Edit 2*: I wanted to clarify: By 'save', I meant that I didn't want to have to save it to a special location, be that a (flash) drive or uploading to the web. Saving to the local hard drive is fine (and probably necessary, since technologies such as Bluetooth require the file to be saved somewhere).

This is a bit inspired by a scene in Avatar, so I highly doubt that this actually exists... but if it does, I don't want to miss out.

Comment: Google Docs allows for easily working on the same document from multiple computers.. But that's working in the cloud, so I guess doesn't answer your question? (And Super User does not like questions on online services like Google Docs.)

Comment: Saving does not only apply to putting something on a flash drive; services like http://www.dropbox.com synchronize files between computers on the fly. Still, this would need you to save, and re-open elsewhere, so doesn't meet your criteria.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine it would be fairly simple to set something like this up, if it doesn't already exist. For example, you could have either a client-server or peer-to-peer setup where both computers communicate with one another, and, at some signal, pass information from one to the other.

For all intents and purposes, though, you are still "saving" the document onto the other computer, albeit in memory if not onto a hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like some remote desktop. Windows Professional [supports it](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsXp/using/mobility/getstarted/Remoteintro.mspx), but you'd need a computer that operates as the host; it's not really transferring state to another machine.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Live Mesh.  Description from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_Mesh):

> Live Mesh is a data synchronization
>   system from Microsoft  that allows
>   files, folders and other data to be
>   shared and synchronized across
>   multiple personal devices ...  Once a
>   folder is set for synchronization, it
>   will be available in all devices, and
>   any changes made to the content of the
>   folder will be reflected across all
>   devices.

Works on Windows and Mac.  Live Mesh web site is at mesh.com

Answer (score 0):

Consider [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/). It's "in the cloud" as you say. Not sure if that's what you want though. If you want to transfer files though you need to have some transfer medium, and if you don't want to use a memory stick, that only really leaves cloud solutions.

It syncs files between computers.

Supports Windows, Mac and Linux

(Very similar to Mesh which [lundmark](https://superuser.com/questions/117261/transferring-live-documents-to-another-computer/117267#117267) has suggested)

Answer (score 0):

As has already been mentioned, Remote Desktop for Windows does this. For linux there's FreeNX or NeatX. The theory being you're doing your work remotely, so you can connect to your session from different locations, maintaining the same state. Your USB drives or peripherals can be tunneled through to the server.